# pandas.DataFrame.reindex

Tags: python-3.7, jupyter

Intento cambiar la etiqueta de las columnas de un DataFrame, utilizando el método `pandas.DataFrame.reindex`, de dos formas diferentes y siempre me devuelve un DataFrame con la etiqueta de las columnas modificada, pero vacío, con NaN en todos los registros

Opción 1

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 2000],
                   'two': [1000, 0, 30, 40, 50, 60]})
new_index = ["uno", "dos"]
df.reindex(new_index)
```

Opción 2

```
df = df.reindex(index=[0, 1], columns=[
                              "uno", "dos"])

print(df)
```

Me devuelven.
uno  dos
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN

¿Cuál es mi -error?

Comment: ¿Pero.. por qué `reindex` para cambiar el nombre de las columnas? si es solo eso, puedes hacerlo así  `df.columns = ['uno, 'dos']`

Comment: y la opción 2? :/

Comment: Efectivamente, esa sentencia es mucho más sencilla, pero, ¿por qué me falla reindex?

Comment: Por que reindex es una función usada para modificar el índice del dataframe no para modificar los nombres de las columnas.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho también sirve para renombrar las columnas, la propia documentación lo dice

Comment: @Christian, No, no hace eso, al menos según lo que se dice aquí:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html